# отправка ID сессии Java

Tags: java, сессия

Здравствуйте.
Столкнулся с проблемой на клиент-серверном приложении. При успешной авторизации клиента (Post-запрос) - сервер генерирует sessionID и отправляет его клиенту.
Как используюя этот ID постоянно передавать в дальнейшем его на сервер?
У web-клиента этот параметр передается в coockie. Как реализовать его аналогичным образом в приложении?

Comment: Передавать авторизационный токен query-параметром или заголовком.

Comment: У меня нету возможности изменения сервера. Есть ли стандартное решение подобной ситуации?
Отправить я могу без проблем, вопрос в том, правильно ли прочтет это сервер.

Comment: Так же куком и отправлять назад на сервер. Не знаете что ли как извлечь кук из http ответа сервер и вставить его в http запрос?

Comment: Как извлечь - знаю.
Как отправить - нет.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
HttpURLConnection newConn = (HttpURLConnection) newUrl.openConnection();
newConn.setRequestProperty("Cookie",SessionID);
```